# Voronoi summation formula

Tags: calculus

I see in one paper that
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{4} k \text{csch}^2\left(\frac{1}{2} k p \log (2)\right)=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } k \sigma _0(k) 2^{-k p}$$
Where the divisor function is $$\sigma _0(k)$$
any idea I try to use the alambert generating function but do not work

Comment: please format the equation - add spaces. Otherwise it is unreadable.

Comment: *Hint.* We have the following expansion: when $\Re(p) > 0$, $$ \frac{\operatorname{csch}^2(\frac{1}{2}kp \log 2)}{4} = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} j 2^{-jkp}. $$